# TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'",)

Tags: python

```
import math

A = input("Enter Wright in KG PLease :")
B = input("Enter Height in Meters Please :")



while (any(x.isalpha() for x in A)):
    print("No Letters Please")
    A = input("Enter Wright in KG PLease ")
    B = input("Enter Height in Meters Please ")

D = B ** 2

C = (float(A) / float(D))


print(C)

if  C <= 18.5: 
 print("Your Under Weight")

elif  C >= 18.5 and C <= 24.9:
  print ("Your Heathy Weight")

elif C >= 25.0 and C <= 29.0:
  print ("Your Over Weight")
```

I keep getting TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'",)  I want to square the user input B and i don't know why sorry if this sounds really dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing

```
B = float(input( "Enter Height in meters : "))
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but now in my loop i am getting ValueError("could not convert string to float: 'a'",)

Comment: do the same for a too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this less complicated by casting to float and catching `ValueError` to detect invalid input. Note that it'd be more user-friendly to split this into two `while` loops, one each for `a` and `b`, but this is just to illustrate the idea:

```
a = b = None

while not (a and b):
    try:
        a = float(input("Weight (kg): "))
        b = float(input("Height (m): "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")

c = a / (b ** 2)

if c <= 18.5:
    print("Underweight")
elif 18.5 < c < 25:
    print("Healthy weight")
else:
    print("Overweight")
```

Also, `not (a and b)` will keep requesting input in the event that one of the inputs was zero, which I think is appropriate behavior in this case.